# Sqlite Batch Insertion Becoming slower after deployment to client's machine

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a C# windows application, sometimes the application would be used to import records from excel file, i could import 2500 records in one minute using batch insertion on my development machine, when i tried normal regular insertion approach, it also took the same one minute to insert 2500 records, this get worse after i have deployed the application and installed on a client's machine, it took more than two hours to import same number of record, i just felt since i am using bulk insertion, the speed should be greatly optimised, below is my code:

```
 public int InsertTaxRecordBatchTransaction(IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetails)
    {
        SQLiteConnection conn = null;
        SQLiteCommand cmd = null;
        var results = new List<int>();

        try
        {              
            string insert = "INSERT INTO IncomeTax (OrganisationId,OrganisationName,StaffId,StaffName,Department,Position,NoOfMonthsWorked,TaxIdNumber,SessionId,Month,Year,BasicSalaryVALUES (@OrganisationId,@OrganisationName,@StaffId,@StaffName,@Department,@Position,@NoOfMonthsWorked,@TaxIdNumber,@SessionId,@Month,@Year,@BasicSalary);";
            using (conn = new SQLiteConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            //cmd = new SQLiteCommand(insert, conn);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.CommandText = insert;
                            cmd.CommandTimeout = 900000000;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrganisationId", DbType.String, 50).Value = OrganisationId;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrganisationName", DbType.String, 50).Value = OrganisationName;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", DbType.String, 50).Value = StaffId;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffName", DbType.String, 50).Value = StaffName;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", DbType.String, 50).Value = Department;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", DbType.String, 50).Value = Position;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoOfMonthsWorked", DbType.Int16, 5).Value = NoOfMonthsWorked;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxIdNumber", DbType.String, 5).Value = TaxIdNumber;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionId", DbType.String, 20).Value = SessionId;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", DbType.String, 20).Value = Month;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", DbType.String, 20).Value = Year;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BasicSalary", DbType.Decimal, 2).Value = BasicSalary;

                            foreach (var employee in employeeDetails)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrganisationId", DbType.String, 50).Value = employee.OrganisationId;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrganisationName", DbType.String, 50).Value = employee.OrganisationName;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", DbType.String, 50).Value = employee.StaffId;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StaffName", DbType.String, 50).Value = employee.StaffName;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", DbType.String, 50).Value = employee.Department;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Position", DbType.String, 50).Value = employee.Position;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoOfMonthsWorked", DbType.Int16, 5).Value = employee.NoOfMonthsWorked;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaxIdNumber", DbType.String, 5).Value = employee.TaxIdNumber;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SessionId", DbType.String, 20).Value = employee.SessionId;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", DbType.String, 20).Value = employee.Month;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", DbType.String, 20).Value = employee.Year;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BasicSalary", DbType.Decimal, 2).Value = employee.BasicSalary;

                                results.Add(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
                            }

                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                        DspMsg = "Tax computed successfully!";
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        DspMsg = ex.Message+ " some errors have occured, no record was saved! ";
                    }
                }
            }
           // conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {

            DspMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        return results.Sum();
    }
```

I dont know where i have got it wrong, i will appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Is your development machine equivalent to the clients production machine?   You know, does your dev machine has 16GB of ram and 8 quad core processors backed off 4 High performance SSD drives,   and the clients machine is a 1 core machine with 2GB of ram and a single spinning disk,   and that machine runs the clients entire business?      That would be the first thing I would look at.

Comment: i also installed on my system to test, it also took a long time(the same two hours it took in other machines, secondary, my dev machine is even lower than the clients'

Comment: The code looks OK (except for the missing space before VALUES). But the loop calls `Parameters.Add` for each entry. Does `Parameters.Add` ignore duplicates?